# How to solve this problem (404 Not Found) while updating

Tags: 14.04

```
sudo apt-get update W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tahutek-team/prozilla/ubuntu
/dists/wily/main/source/Sources 404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tahutek-team/prozilla/ubuntu/dists/wily/main
/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with some more information, because at first thought it looks like your `sources.list` file has an issue - but it could be more complex than that. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/740886/edit) your post with a copy & paste of the information found by using this command (in the terminal): `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Also copy and paste the result of the following command too: `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://ppa.launchpad.net/tahutek-team/prozilla/ubuntu/dists/, you will see that they are not mirroring the **wily** distribution.

I'm not sure why your sources are set to point there though. You might want to either contact the mirror owner (https://launchpad.net/~tahutek-team), or update your `sources.list` file (found at `/etc/apt/sources.list`) to point to a valid wily repository.

You can use the instructions at [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) to reset your repositories to the default.